# After 24 Hours of recent status, create new status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3.2 Twitter App.

SOLUTION: Props to correct answer. I overlook the simple stuff sometimes. Ended up putting a line into my huge view. It was easier to me. Looks like this.

```
<% @ribbits.each do |ribbit| %>

<% if ribbit.user != current_user%>

<% if ribbit.user.following? current_user %>

<% if ribbit.created_at > (Time.now - 1.day) %>

etc.
```

I've got one last feature I'm trying to figure out. If a user's most recent status was created more than 24 hours ago, I'd like to create a new status of "yadayadayada" for them.

Here's how the most recent status is displayed.

`users_controller.rb`

```
def buddies
 @ribbits = Ribbit.where("(ribbits.user_id, ribbits.created_at) IN (SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) FROM ribbits WHERE user_id IN (?) GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC LIMIT 10)", buddies_ids).order("created_at DESC")
```

`/users/buddies.html.erb`

```
<% @ribbits.each do |ribbit| %> ... etc
```

Something like this is either going in my `users_controller.rb` or `ribbits_controller.rb`

```
if @ribbits.user.ribbit created_at > (Time.now - 1.day)
  Ribbit.new(:status => "sdfaklsdf")
end
```

Ribbits are tweets.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can i after 24 Hours of a recent status, create new status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need this "default" status in the database, then you can just push the logic into the User model.

Something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def current_ribbit
    if ribbit created_at > (Time.now - 1.day)
      default_ribbit
    else
      ribbit
    end
  end

  def self.default_ribbit
    Ribbit.new(:status => "sdfaklsdf")
  end

end
```

Comment: You are a smart cookie. I will try this.

Comment: Ending up putting it into my view with `if ribbit.created_at > Time.now - 1.day` then I displayed `- - -` THANKS

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking of is a scheduler. You can use [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) for this. Sidekiq let's you create [jobs at a specific time](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs).